# MultiThreading in winform c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I Want to know that i have define a function in form

Eg:Dynamically Display (Running) Current Date Time

It display the current system time on that form

Is it possible to call the same function without creating a new function on each and every form?

please help

Comment: You can use inheritance with Forms. But what does this have to do with threading?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. Do you want to call `DateTime.Now` on every form for a label or something?

Comment: Yes i want to call it on each and every form

Comment: @user3327117: You can use `static` function , check the answer below

Comment: And still, what has that to do with threading? Question is totally unclear.

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP wants to update that time every second (based on "dynamically" and "running")

Comment: i want to define a function in one form and want to use the same function on multiple form
Date time Function that i want to call on each and every page

Comment: that runs dynamically

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** You dont need to write a function for this:

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

**Solution 2:** but if you want to access it using function create a static function

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static string DisplayDateTime()
    {
         return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Call the above function wherever you want as below:

```
 Label1.Text = Utility.DisplayDateTime();
```

**Solution 3:** if you want to change datetime for every second try this:

```
    public static class Utility
    {
        public static string DisplayDateTime()
        {
             return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer1.Interval=1000;//one second
    timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //do whatever you want 
         Label1.Text = Utility.DisplayDateTime();
    }
```

Comment: i can call the fuction on any form i want to call?

Comment: @user3327117: sorry i didn't get you. could you please explain it?

Comment: I want to call the datetime fuction that runs dynamically on each and every form in my project

Comment: @user3327117: if you want to change the datetime value for every second check my `solution3`